# How to call startcoroutine from editor script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the mono script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateOnTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;

    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;

    public Terrain terrain;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public float instantiateTime;
    public float yOffset;


    void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        StartCoroutine(generateObjectsOnTerrain());
    }

    IEnumerator generateObjectsOnTerrain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            float objOffsetX = prefab.transform.localScale.x / 2;
            float objOffsetZ = prefab.transform.localScale.z / 2;

            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos + objOffsetX, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth - objOffsetX);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos + objOffsetZ, zTerrainPos + terrainLength - objOffsetZ);
            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            //Generate the Prefab on the generated position
            GameObject objInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);

            if (instantiateTime > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(instantiateTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the editor script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.TerrainTools;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(InstantiateOnTerrain))]
public class InstantiateOnTerrainEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        InstantiateOnTerrain onTerrain = (InstantiateOnTerrain)target;
        if(GUILayout.Button("Instiante Objects"))
        {
            onTerrain.generateObjectsOnTerrain();
        }
    }
}
```

I want that either in editor mode or runtime when I click the button in the editor script that it will start Instantiate the objects.

the problem is that the method generateObjectsOnTerrain is type IEnumerator and there is no coroutine in editor script. I can't make StartCoroutine in the editor script.

Comment: Coroutines only work in playmode, so that behaviour is not supported natively.
There is [a hacky way](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1413012/view.html) around this though, by latching on to the `EditorApplication.update` callback, you can execute coroutines from editor scripts still. I haven't been able to confirm if it works myself, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the package and use [`EditorCoroutineUtility.StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.editorcoroutines@1.0/api/Unity.EditorCoroutines.Editor.EditorCoroutineUtility.html)

My question however: In the editor do you really want to have this as a routine with a time delay? I would rather suggest that on edit time you do not care about any freezes/delays so rather generate the entire thing and only use a routine on runtime.

In general in editor scripts you want to avoid going through the `target` directly and use "normal" runtime API. If done wrong (as in your case) this can yield all kinds of issues with dirty marking, undo/redo and saving of changes. For the editor version you would rather generate the thing in one go and use e.g. [`PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab.html)